# Testing in Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-web-developer

I have to write a unit test of my web application (ASP.NET - C#). So far I know very little about testing, I have read everywhere that express edition doesn't support testing at all and so far I haven't found any other way to achieve my goal. I was wondering if there is a way to walk around it somehow and (if there isn't it is weird that I got this task) and how to implement the test itself. Would anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the tests from within Visual Studio by creating a Class Library and importing nunit.framework. However, you will be unable to run your tests from within Visual Studio due to the EULA preventing third-party add-ins. You can however, run them from the command line

Refer to nunit's page on Running Tests found [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=runningTests&r=2.6)

I would assume you could also set up the command line to run as a post-build command if you wanted as well